# Dynamic array of queue and associative array

Tags: multidimensional-array, system-verilog, associative-array

```
int c[][$][int];
```

I am trying to understand memories in depth. I was just wondering whether a 3D dynamic array with queue and associative array is possible or not?

I am able to make 2D dynamic array with queue like this:

```
int a[][$];
```

and it's working.  I am able to write data in each location and retrieve as well.

I am stuck with `int c[][$][$]` and `int c[][$][int]`.

I used this logic for 2D dynamic array with queue.

```
initial
    a=new[4];
         foreach(a[i])
            begin
                a[i].push_front(i*2);
                a[i].push_front(i*3);
                a[i].push_front(i*4);
            end

        $display("arr %0p size=%0d",a,$size(a));            
        
        foreach(a[i])
            for(int j=0; j<3;j++)
            begin
                b[l] =a[i].pop_front();
                l++;
            end
        $display("%0p",b);
end
```

For 3D, I was trying this:

```
initial
    begin
        c=new[4];
        foreach(c[i])
             a[i].push_front(i*2);
        $display("%0p",c);
    end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you didn't add anything to `c` in your `foreach` loop.

If `c` is an array of queues of queues, you can push multiple copies of the `a[i]` queue, for example:

```
module tb;

int a[][$];
int c[][$][$];

initial begin
    a = new[4];
    foreach (a[i]) begin
        a[i].push_front(i*2);
        a[i].push_front(i*3);
        a[i].push_front(i*4);
    end
    $display;
    $display("a %p size=%0d", a, $size(a));
    $display;

    c = new[4];
    foreach (c[i]) begin
        c[i].push_front( a[i] );
        c[i].push_front( a[i] );
    end
    $display("c %p", c);
    $display;
end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
a '{'{0, 0, 0}, '{4, 3, 2}, '{8, 6, 4}, '{12, 9, 6}} size=4

c '{'{'{0, 0, 0}, '{0, 0, 0}}, '{'{4, 3, 2}, '{4, 3, 2}}, '{'{8, 6, 4}, '{8, 6, 4}}, '{'{12, 9, 6}, '{12, 9, 6}}}
```

With an associative array:

```
module tb;

int c[][$][int];

initial begin
    c = new[4];
    foreach (c[i]) begin
        c[i].push_front( '{ 3 : i+4 } );
        c[i].push_front( '{ 7 : i+1 } );
    end
    $display("c %p", c);
end
endmodule
```

Output:

```
c '{'{'{7:1}, '{3:4}}, '{'{7:2}, '{3:5}}, '{'{7:3}, '{3:6}}, '{'{7:4}, '{3:7}}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Think of this way: SystemVerilog only has single dimensional arrays, but each element can be of any data type, including another array. This is known as *arrays_of_arrays*. For dynamically-sized arrays, like queues, dynamic, and associative arrays, you need to make sure each array element gets sized before accessing the next layer.

```
int c[][$][int];
initial begin
  c= new[4]; // creates an array of 4 empty queues
  foreach(c[i])
    repeat(i+1) 
      c[i].push_back('{default:0})
end
```

This creates a *triangular* shaped dynamic array of queues, where each element is an empty associative array. You can an assignment

```
 c[3][3][234] = 42;
```

but the element `c[1][3]` does not exist yet.